# is it possible for a normal user to access the button only for the management, by inspecting a website and enable the hidden button?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

develop website for user and the management

for example

normal users has identity of 1, therefore if account has id of 1. they can access the page limiting what they can do. in the same way the management is 2, the management and normal users access the same page but limit by their identity.

```
let user_id = ref('1');
let user_id = ref('2');
```

in the same page, their is button available only for the management and is hidden

```
display : none;
```

if the user_id is equal to 2. it will show.

but i was thinking if the normal user can inspect the website and show the display button and he/she can do what the management does.?

Comment: You are right. When you have CSS code `display: none;` in the HTML page source, that is a very easy hack. However the button's action **should be checked on the servers side also**.

Answer (score 1):

On permissioned pages you should use `v-if` instead of `v-show`.

**`v-if`**: will make the dom node disappear.

**`v-show`**: Call `display:none` to control whether the element is displayed.

example:

```
<button v-if="userId === 1">normal user</button>
<button v-if="userId === 2">administrator</button>
```

Or

If you only have normal users or administrators:

```
<button v-if="userId === 2">administrator</button>
<button v-else>normal user</button>
```

Comment: im gonna try this, thanks bro for help

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to stop non-eligible users from clicking on that button-

**1. Using v-if directive-**

v-show is fast than v-if because the element will always render no matter if the condition is true or false. It uses CSS-based toggling but v-if is real condition rendering which means the element will not render unless the condition is true.

So, you can use v-if to render the button in DOM only for eligible users. So, non-eligible users won't be able to inspect it.

```
<button v-if="eligible">click</button>
```

**2. Using the condition on click**

Even if the user is able to inspect and show the button, you can apply a check on its click, that which user is triggering the action. For example-

```
<button @click="onClick()">Click Me</button>
```

```
onClick() {
  if(loggedin_user_id == 1) {
    alert("You are not allowed to do this action")
  }
}
```

**Both approaches are useful if you are performing any action only on the client side. But on the button's click, if you are sending any API request or anything else related to the backend, the security checks should be applied to the backend as well.**

Comment: thanks will take this in mind. thanks for help. sensei